# Dos v-model en un mismo input Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js

Estoy practicando con Vue.js 2, y me surge la necesidad de usar dos **v-model** dentro de un mismo input. ¿Habrá alguna manera de realizar dicha tarea?
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<b-form-input type="search" v-model="codigoArticulo" v-model="registro.datosArticulo"></b-form-input>
```

El primer **v-model="codigoArticulo"** dirige a una **función dentro de watch** que hace seguimiento al artículo por código y muestra su nombre en otro input como parte del formulario. El segundo **v-model="registro.datosArticulo"** dirige a una **función dentro de methods** que agrega el registro de todo el formulario en general.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder usar los dos **v-model** u otra alternativa para **usar las dos funciones** desde el **mismo input**?

PD: Intenté migrar a Vue 3, tengo muchos errores de compatibilidad, por sigo en Vue 2 con esta práctica.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: deberias sacar el ``v-model="registro.datosArticulo"`` y hacer una funcion que agregue el registro al darle click a un boton o algo asi, ya que no vas a poder meter dos v-model en un componente y para lo que queres basta con armar una funcion que cargue el registro y una accion que dispare dicha funcion

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te ayude yo tengo el mismo problema,
https://escuelavue.es/cursos/curso-vue3-esencial-novedades/vue3-multiple-v-model/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/321944)